# Image follows the cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help trying to do following:

One: Click once to begin the image to follow
Two: Click again to stop the image 
Three: It will notify which of the two states the user is in

My jfiddle code example is below.

```
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
    $("#giraffeImg").stop().animate({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sure1thing/5q8zH/4/

Thanks

Comment: it's still unclear to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
var follow = false;
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e)
{
    //console.log(e.pageX);
    if(follow)
    {
        //alert('follow true');
        $('#image').animate({
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY
        }, 0)
    }
})

$(document).click(function()
{
    if(follow)
    {  
        follow = false; 
    }
    else
    {
        follow = true;   
    }
})
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5q8zH/6/)**

I just use a "flag" to start and stop the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/5q8zH/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var count = 0,
        anim = function(e){
        $("#giraffeImg").stop().animate({left:e.pageX,      top:e.pageY});
    }


    $(this).click(function(e){
        count += 1;

        if(count % 2){
        console.log('Animation started')

        $(this).on('mousemove',anim);  

        }else{
         $(this).off('mousemove', anim);

         console.log('Animation finished')
        }
})  

})
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is if statement is trying to do?         if(count % 2){

Comment: How can I stop the message in <h2 id="giraffelocation"></h2> from repeating? I would like the a message to display inside a div when the giraffe is moving. When you click again, the message will be replaced with another message. [**jfiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/RGJpE/)

Comment: In place of append use html.